# Prevent one jQuery Event with another

Tags: jquery, events, onclick, event-handling

In order to tidy up my jQuery, I am looking to create a "confirm" class for various elements with event handlers so I can fire off a quick confirmation box so the user can confirm their action.

If the user clicks cancel on the confirmation box, any following events should be cancelled, but this should **not** be permanent, eg triggering the event again should bring up the confirmation and start again. If I can work this out I can make any sensitive action have a confirmation question to make sure the user meant to click.

For example:

```
$('.confirm').click(function() {
    if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        // Stop any other click events on $(this) from happening this instance.
    }
});

$('.clicker').click(function() {
    alert('it happened');
});

<a class="clicker confirm">Click me</a>
```

Desired output would be that cancelling the confirmation would cancel the click event, but not totally disable it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) from jQuery:

```
$('.confirm').click(function(event) {
    if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();

        // Stop any other click events on $(this) from happening this instance.
    }
});

$('.clicker').click(function() {
    alert('it happened');
});
```

Look at [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5uJPu/)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I intended to do. Messed up TWICE in my answer so decided to delete it instead ;) thanks for refreshing my mind!

Comment: I'd like to add, in the case of forms, event.preventDefault() is also required to stop the form from firing when you deny the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.confirm').click(function() {     
return confirm('Are you sure?');
});
```

you can also use  `event.stopPropagation()` in side your click event to stop furthure propagation.

Comment: I found that return false didn't stop other click events from being triggered.

Comment: Sadly, `.disablePropagation()` doesn't exist. It was my bad, and it should be `.stopPropagation()`, which doesn't work either. Nicola presented the correct solution!